# Getting Arizona time with getTime()

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, gettime

```
date= Calendar.getInstance();
Date currentDate = date.getTime();
String sDate = currentDate.toString();
```

This returns time EST. I need to change it to Arizona time which is tricky because Arizona does not have daylight savings time.  Is there a short cut to making the changes or do I need to query a calendar to subtract two hours when Arizona is on MST and three hours when PST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This returns time EST.

Well, `Date.toString()` will, if you're *in* EST at the moment. It's not part of the data stored within the `Date` - that's just an instant in time, with no idea what time zone or calendar system it might have started off in.

Your first two lines would be more simply written as:

```
Date currentDate = new Date();
```

You should use a `DateFormat` to convert the `Date` into a `String`. You can specify the time zone you want to use there. Do *not* start performing any arithmetic on the date yourself to add/remove offsets - that's a sign that you're heading in the wrong direction.

Comment: I am in Arizona and it is returning EST.

Comment: @Aaron: That suggests that your device (or emulator) doesn't know the time zone properly, basically. Try logging `TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  The Emulator is giving me EST.  Didn't even think to look at it